# Python: Repeating a function when raw_input is not valid

Tags: python, while-loop, raw-input

I'm want to be able to determine if an input is valid. I have:

```
servqual = raw_input(">").lower()
while servqual != "great" or "good" or "lacking" or "poor":
    print "I didn't understand that. Please try again."
    servqual = raw_input(">").lower()
```

However, whenever I run it through the loop it always assumes True, even if I input a valid answer.
I've looked over different answers but none of them seem to work in this scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
servqual != "great" or "good" or "lacking" or "poor"
```

is equivalent to

```
(servqual != "great") or "good" or "lacking" or "poor"
```

And since Strings are considered `True`, you are always getting it True

The correct way to do it is

```
servqual != "great" and servqual != "good" and servqual != "lacking" and servqual != "poor"
```

or

```
servqual not in ("great", "good", "lacking", "poor")
```

Your final code will look like

```
servqual = raw_input(">").lower()
while servqual not in ("great", "good", "lacking", "poor"):
    print "I didn't understand that. Please try again."
    servqual = raw_input(">").lower()
```

You can further improve it by using following construct.

```
while raw_input(">").lower() not in ("great", "good", "lacking", "poor"):
    print "I didn't understand that. Please try again."
```

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
while servqual != "great" or "good" or "lacking" or "poor":
```

This means the same as:

```
while (servqual != "great") or "good" or "lacking" or "poor"
```

Since `"good" or "lacking" or "poor"` is always true, the whole condition is true.

Rather than that, you can do this:

```
while servqual not in ("great", "good", "lacking", "poor"):
    ...
```